# symfony asserts regex

Tags: symfony

anyone know how to make a regular expression to not allow the user to enter numbers in a field? Something seemed to this:

```
/**
  * @Assert\Regex("/^\w+/")
 */
```

a greeting. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this work. (not tested)

```
  /**  
   * @Assert\Regex("/^[^0-9]+$/") 
   */
```